# What do glAttachShader and glLinkShader actually do?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, shader

As these steps are followed to create a shader program which can later be used to draw an object on the screen.

```
glCreateShader  -> glShaderSource -> glCompileShader ->
glCreateProgram -> glAttachShader -> glLinkProgram   -> glUseProgram
```

What does glAttachShader do?

- Does it copy shader object inside program object? or it just indicates that these shader objects will be copied during linking?
- doc : https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glAttachShader.xhtml

What does glLinkProgram do?

- What is the meaning of linking a program object?
- Does it check if shader objects are copied inside program object correctly? and all the shader stages exist that are needed to draw?
- doc : https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glLinkProgram.xhtml

Comment: The [OpenGL 4.6 core profile specification - 7.3 Program Objects, page 94](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) says: Shader objects may be attached to program objects before source code has been loaded into the shader object, or before the shader object has been compiled or specialized. - In general the specification does not say anything about the linking has to be done. It only specifies the result of the linking.

Comment: If you want more specific info, please elaborate on what you want to understand. As it stands, your question is very broad since it's not clear which level of detail you want and for which step.

Comment: I would like to understand what happens when glAttachShader() is called. As the documentation says that the function attaches shader object to program object - what does this mean? Does shader object get linked to program object somehow? if yes, how?
Another question is when glLinkProgram() is called, does an executable file of program object is created which then goes to the server of Opengl? what are the steps that take place during the linking of program object? (eg: coping shader objects inside program object, checking variable compatibility that go from one shader stage to another)

Comment: I just stumbled upon this old unanswered question, but correct me if I'm wrong: OpenGL is just a standardized API to interface with your graphics drivers. The actual details of compiling and linking shaders will depend on the driver in question. Nvidia and AMD have developed their own shader compilers and linkers that output executable code that is compatible with their GPUs. "Compiling" and "Linking" are generally the same procedures across different programming languages, including GLSL. (Each shader is a compilation unit, and the linker combines them into an executable.)